# Conditionally lifting protocols to generic types in Swift

Tags: swift, types

How do I say in Swift's type system "an `Array<T>` conforms to protocol `P` if the element type `T` conforms to protocol `Q`"?

I'm actually interested in a more specific version of this problem, where `P` and `Q` are the same protocol: you're saying "if the elements of the array are `P`-conforming, then the array is `P`-conforming". Here's what I have so far. (I'm trying for a simple QuickCheck library, starting from http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/quickcheck-in-swift.html: `Arbitrary` marks types that can be randomly generated.)

```
protocol Arbitrary {
    class func arbitrary() -> Self
}
extension Array {
    static func arbitrary<T where T : Arbitrary>() -> [T] {
        // code to create a random-length list of T objects
        // using T.arbitrary() for each one 
    }
}
extension Array<T where T : Arbitrary> : Arbitrary {}
```

This fails with the error

```
extension of generic type 'Array' cannot add requirements
extension Array<T where T : Arbitrary> : Arbitrary {}
```

Comment: For future googlers: check the current state of Swift, this feature is (tentatively) planned as part of "[Completing Generics](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/8484)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Swift, since you can't further constrain a generic type. For example, you can't add methods to `Array<T>` that only work when `T` is `Comparable` - that's why there are so many global functions for dealing with generic types (map, filter, sort, etc.).

From a recent Chris Lattner posts in the dev forums, it sounds like the Swift developers are headed in this direction, but it's nowhere near this yet. See if you can implement what you're trying to do as global functions that constrain `T` to `Arbitrary`:

```
func arbitrary<T: Arbitrary>() -> [T] {
    // ..
}
```